# in golang, is there any performance difference between maps initialized using make vs {}

Tags: performance, go

as we know there are two ways to initialize a map (as listed below). I'm wondering if there is any performance difference between the two approaches.

```
var myMap map[string]int
```

then

```
myMap = map[string]int{}
```

vs

```
myMap = make(map[string]int)
```

Comment: According to the documentation initialize a map literal it is 'functional identical' to do it with 'make'. I think this could be take as performance ==.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my machine they appear to be about equivalent.

You can easily make a benchmark test to compare.  For example:

```
package bench

import "testing"

var result map[string]int

func BenchmarkMakeLiteral(b *testing.B) {
        var m map[string]int
        for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
                m = InitMapLiteral()
        }
        result = m
}

func BenchmarkMakeMake(b *testing.B) {
        var m map[string]int
        for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
                m = InitMapMake()
        }
        result = m
}

func InitMapLiteral() map[string]int {
        return map[string]int{}
}

func InitMapMake() map[string]int {
        return make(map[string]int)
}
```

Which on 3 different runs yielded results that are close enough to be insignificant:

#### First Run

```
$ go test -bench=.
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
BenchmarkMakeLiteral-8  10000000               160 ns/op
BenchmarkMakeMake-8     10000000               171 ns/op
ok      github.com/johnweldon/bench     3.664s
```

#### Second Run

```
$ go test -bench=.
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
BenchmarkMakeLiteral-8  10000000               182 ns/op
BenchmarkMakeMake-8     10000000               173 ns/op
ok      github.com/johnweldon/bench     3.945s
```

#### Third Run

```
$ go test -bench=.
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
BenchmarkMakeLiteral-8  10000000               170 ns/op
BenchmarkMakeMake-8     10000000               170 ns/op
ok      github.com/johnweldon/bench     3.751s
```

Answer (score 4):

When allocating empty maps there is no difference but with `make` you can pass second parameter to pre-allocate space in map. This will save a lot of reallocations when maps are being populated.

### Benchmarks

```
package maps

import "testing"

const SIZE = 10000

func fill(m map[int]bool, size int) {
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        m[i] = true
    }
}

func BenchmarkEmpty(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        m := make(map[int]bool)
        fill(m, SIZE)
    }
}

func BenchmarkAllocated(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        m := make(map[int]bool, 2*SIZE)
        fill(m, SIZE)
    }
}
```

### Results

```
go test -benchmem -bench .
BenchmarkEmpty-8             500       2988680 ns/op      431848 B/op        625 allocs/op
BenchmarkAllocated-8        1000       1618251 ns/op      360949 B/op         11 allocs/op
```

Answer (score 0):

A year ago I actually stumped on the fact that using `make` with explicitly allocated space is better then using map literal if your values are not static

So doing

```
return map[string]float {
    "key1": SOME_COMPUTED_ABOVE_VALUE,
    "key2": SOME_COMPUTED_ABOVE_VALUE,
    // more keys here
    "keyN": SOME_COMPUTED_ABOVE_VALUE,
}
```

is slower then

```
// some code above
result := make(map[string]float, SIZE) // SIZE >= N
result["key1"] = SOME_COMPUTED_ABOVE_VALUE
result["key2"] = SOME_COMPUTED_ABOVE_VALUE
// more keys here
result["keyN"] = SOME_COMPUTED_ABOVE_VALUE
return result
```

for N which are quite big (N=300 in my use case).
The reason is the compiler fails to understand that one needs to allocate at least N slots in the first case.

I wrote a blog post about it
https://trams.github.io/golang-map-literal-performance/
and I reported a bug to the community
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/43020

As of golang 1.17 it is still an issue.